# Setting Directory.LastWriteTimeUtc on just created directory throws IOException randomly

Tags: c#, .net, directory, ioexception

following simple code will throw IOException "The process cannot access the file XXX because it is being used by another process." randomly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\ee\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    di.CreationTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    di.LastAccessTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    di.LastWriteTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Why?

And how to avoid this random exception in the best way? Of course I could put each statement into try catch block with retry in catch (this seems to be working in my tests) but is this really the best what I can do?

Using .NET 4.0, antivirus real-time protection is down

Comment: From what I remember of a similar issue I had, its because the directories are still being created, you *may* be able to get around it by keeping a list of the directories and then updating the times in a second loop

Comment: Ok, I would understand if the exception would be thrown always on di.CreationTimeUtc. But exception is being thrown in most of cases on LastWriteTimeUtc which is last in sequence

Comment: Its hard to say.. but then is this really needed? surely the creation time and last write time at least would be set to this time anyway, not sure about access time

Comment: Exception will be thrown even if di.CreationTimeUtc line would not be presented. But still, exception could be thrown on LastWriteTimeUtc  not on always on LastAccessTimeUtc. Therefore comment "directory is still being created" cannot be fully correct

Comment: Is that folder Indexed? Compressed? I can't repro this.

Comment: Nothing. I just created "C:\ee" on HDD to do not have mess on HDD. Then run this code. This should end up in IOException. Tested on Win 7 64bit Ultimate